# Problems with ZeroMQ Connection. No Response to SYN Message

Tags: c#, tcp, zeromq

I'm trying to implement ZeroMQ in my Unity-Project. Since I have some trouble with that, I test it with a seperate c# console Project in Visual Studio 2019.

The Thing is: It works sometimes, but then suddenly it stops working.

I started with testing Pub/Sub sockets between 2 computers and it worked. I also played around with outher Sockets: All worked.

When trying to implement the Sub/Pub Sockets a week (or 2) later, they didnt work. With that I mean, that the messages never arrive.

First I had the problem only, when trying to send from Unity. But while Debugging that and testing things in the console Project, it stopped working there as well.

As I can see it, It does not work from Computer 1 to Computer 2, but the other way around works fine.

When Pub/Sub Sockets stopped working, I tried Request/Receive Sockets. They worked, at least with the Console Project (not in Unity).

Now, suddenly, after installing Wireshark, that stopped working as well.

I can see Computer 2 sending SYN Messages to Computer 1. They arrive at the right port (3030). But Computer 1 never seems to Acknowledge the SYN, although NETSTAT says it is listening:
TCP    0.0.0.0:3030           COMPUTER_NAME:0            LISTENING

Since I have to change and try many things, the implementations are very basic and short, so yi may happen, that I dont close/dispose the Socket. But I restarted Computer 1 multiple times. If someone has a solution, how to close a console Application (because it is stuck waiting for a message), but close and dispose the Socket before, it would be appreciated.

COMPUTER 1:

```
using (ResponseSocket server = new ResponseSocket())
{
        int port = 3030;
        server.Bind($"tcp://*:{port}");
        int i = 0;


        Console.WriteLine($"Server is listening on port {port}");

        while (true)
        {
            string message = server.ReceiveFrameString();
            Console.WriteLine($"Received: {message}");

            string response = $"Thank you, for your message: {i}";
            server.SendFrame(response);
            Console.WriteLine($"Response sent: {response}");
            i++;
            Thread.Sleep(500);

            if (i > 20) break;
        }

}
```

COMPUTER 2

```
using (RequestSocket client = new RequestSocket())
{
    string ipAddress = "XX.XX.XXX.XXX"; // Ip Adress is censored
    int port = 3030;
    client.Connect($"tcp://{ipAddress}:{port}");
    int i = 0;


    Console.WriteLine($"Connecting to " + $"tcp://{ipAddress}:{port}");

    while (true)
    {
        string message = i.ToString();
        client.SendFrame(message);
        Console.WriteLine($"Sent: {message}");

        string response = client.ReceiveFrameString();
        Console.WriteLine($"Message received: {response}");
        i++;
        Thread.Sleep(500);

        if (i > 20) break;
    }

}
```

Since Communication with normal Sockets (Not Zero-/Net- MQ) work fine, I know the IpAdresses should not be the Problem.

Thanks for your replies!

Comment: Fromcmd.exe use ">Netstat -a" to troubleshoot.  The server need to be in listen mode.  I suspect it is in Time Wait which means the connection is half open - half closed.  Time Wait occurs when both client and server simultaneously attempts to close a connection.  Then a new connection cannot complete.  Or the connection already exists and a second connection cannot be made until first is closed.  You can use Netstat at both client and server.

Comment: The status is listening: `TCP    0.0.0.0:3030           COMPUTER_NAME:0            LISTENING`

Comment: I think the listener is working.  Are you receiving from more than one connection? When receiving from more than one client you need to use the Async Listener.   Each connection is a different socket.  The Accept method parameter ar is the socket that you use to send the response.

Comment: I the scope of this testing I'm doing, I'm only receiving from 1 Client. I have only the 2 Computers and the Code I put in the question is used just once. So computer 1 uses the code titled: "COMPUTER 1" and computer 2 is using the code titled "COMPUTER 2".

Comment: You cannot have two connections with the same three properties 1) Source IP 2) Destination IP 3) Port Number.  So if you want two connections (computer 1 to 2, and 2 to 1) use two port numbers.  Most likely it is working when the one connection closes before second opens.  Not a good design.